# How to replace a word which occurs before another word in python

Tags: python, text

I want to replace(re-spell) a word A in a text string with another word B if the word A occurs before an operator. Word A can be any word.
E.G:

```
Hi I am Not == you
```

Since "Not" occurs before operator "==", I want to replace it with alist["Not"]
So, above sentence should changed to

```
Hi I am alist["Not"] == you
```

Another example

```
My height > your height
```

should become

```
My alist["height"] > your height
```

Edit:
On @Paul's suggestion, I am putting the code which I wrote myself.
It works but its too bulky and I am not happy with it.

```
operators = ["==", ">", "<", "!="]        
    text_list = text.split(" ")
    for index in range(len(text_list)):           
        if text_list[index] in operators:
            prev = text_list[index - 1]
            if "." in prev:
                tokens = prev.split(".")
                prev = "alist"
                for token in tokens:
                    prev = "%s[\"%s\"]" % (prev, token)
            else:
                prev = "alist[\"%s\"]" % prev
            text_list[index - 1] = prev
    text = " ".join(text_list)
```

Comment: Did you tried anything. code ? So that we can help you in a better way

Comment: @PaulRooney - I have edited the question using my approach. Please remove the 'on hold' from the question

Comment: I can't. You should click the reopen button. If enough reviewers agree it will be reopened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using regular expressions

```
import re
...
def replacement(match):
    return "alist[\"{}\"]".format(match.group(0))
...
re.sub(r"[^ ]+(?= +==)", replacement, s)
```

If the space between the word and the "==" in your case is not needed, the last line becomes:

```
re.sub(r"[^ ]+(?= *==)", replacement, s)
```

I'd highly recommend you to look into regular expressions, and the python implementation of them, as they are really useful.

Explanation for my solution:

`re.sub(pattern, replacement, s)` replaces occurences of patterns, that are given as regular expressions, with a given string or the output of a function.

I use the output of a function, that puts the whole matched object into the 'alist["..."]' construct. (`match.group(0)` returns the whole match)

`[^ ]` match anything but space.

`+` match the last subpattern as often as possible, but at least once.

`*` match the last subpattern as often as possible, but it is optional.

`(?=...)` is a lookahead. It checks if the stuff after the current cursor position matches the pattern inside the parentheses, but doesn't include them in the final match (at least not in `.group(0)`, if you have groups inside a lookahead, those are retrievable by `.group(index)`).

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [regular expression library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) I was able to create a simple solution to your problem as shown here.

```
import re
data = "Hi I am Not == You"
x = re.search(r'(\w+) ==', data)
print(x.groups())
```

In this code, re.search looks for the pattern of (1 or more) alphanumeric characters followed by operator (" ==") and stores the result ("Hi I am Not ==") in variable x.

Then for swaping you could use the re.sub() method which [CodenameLambda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4696955/codenamelambda) suggested.

I'd also recommend learning how to use regular expressions, as they are useful for solving **many** different problems and are similar between different programming languages

Comment: Thanks @alec-c I keep learning & forgetting the regular expression syntax :D

Comment: No problem happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

```
str = "Hi I am Not == you"
s = str.split()
y = ''
str2 = ''
for x in s:
    if x in "==":
        str2 = str.replace(y, 'alist["'+y+'"]')
        break
    y = x

print(str2)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and try to provide some information and context about the code. 
Thanks.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thanks @anurag-jain but this is very brute force way of solving it. I am looking for a solution in 2 lines, which should be possible usinr re.sub